# How to keep a variable value even after doing run as-> Java Application?

Tags: java, static

I know that when we use static variables the value remains the same for all the instances of a class.

But when I do run as -> Java Application in a class, even the static variable is reinicialized with the default value.

Is there any way to keep a variable value even after doing run as-> Java Application in a class?

Thank you.

Comment: I believe you are asking for a program to save state between executions.  To do this, you will almost certainly want to write to disk.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Once a program terminated, how do you "keep a variable"? You can store its value to a file, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: ...and then read it from disk on launching the program in order to initialize it to the value you wrote to disk...

Comment: "static variables the value remains the same for all the instances of a class" in a particular JVM instance. Each JVM instance will behave independantly of the other and have different values then the other

Comment: @G.Bach I want the variable not to have its value reinicialized im each execution. But your answer was valuable. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you everybody for the answers. All of them are useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save to a file, and read it when you want it again from FILE, I know that's not a good programming standard, if it's related to login credentials.

Static variables works only for runtime execution, so they won't help and can store variables even after program terminates.

Answer (score 0):

Write it into a file once app exits and read it back when app starts. On first launch or when that file is missing use default value.

Answer (score 0):

All data are going to be lost after the program ended. You have to persist the data by using any Database or a text file...

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize the Class instance to a file and re-instantiate it upon execution.

Answer (score 0):

.properties is a file extension for files mainly used in Java related technologies to store the configurable parameters of an application.

You can use a property file to store the variables and update or access them as and when you need

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the **Java Preferences API**:

> The java.util.prefs package provides a way for applications to store
> and retrieve user and system preference and configuration data.

*Source*: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/index.html

---

An **Example** of its simple usage:

```
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;

public class PreferenceTest {
  private Preferences prefs;

  public void setPreference() {
    // This will define a node in which the preferences can be stored
    prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node(this.getClass().getName());
    String ID1 = "Test1";
    String ID2 = "Test2";
    String ID3 = "Test3";

    // First we will get the values
    // Define a boolean value
    System.out.println(prefs.getBoolean(ID1, true));
    // Define a string with default "Hello World
    System.out.println(prefs.get(ID2, "Hello World"));
    // Define a integer with default 50
    System.out.println(prefs.getInt(ID3, 50));

    // now set the values
    prefs.putBoolean(ID1, false);
    prefs.put(ID2, "Hello Europa");
    prefs.putInt(ID3, 45);

    // Delete the preference settings for the first value
    prefs.remove(ID1);

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PreferenceTest test = new PreferenceTest();
    test.setPreference();
  }
}
```

*Source*: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPreferences/article.html